# How to fill in a Bar Chart using an Image instead of a Color?

Tags: androidplot

Is there any way to draw Bar Charts using an image instead of a color ? i.e instead of a bar being red or blue, can it be an image (.jpg, .png, etc..) ??

Like [this](http://www.internet4classrooms.com/excel_picto_chart.htm)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using a [BitmapShader](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapShader.html) with your bar's fill paint instance:

```
BarFormatter formatter = new BarFormatter();
formatter.getFillPaint().setShader(myBitmapShader);
```

Creating and using a BitmapShader can be a little tricky and the process is fairly subjective depending on exactly how you want things to look.  [Here's a tutorial](http://www.curious-creature.org/2012/12/13/android-recipe-2-fun-with-shaders/) that I personally found very helpful.